# Create a stretchy line between two objects?

Tags: animation, physics, cloth-simulation, soft-body

So I want to create this stretchy rope effect as seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYpxRJpJGsw).

I want to use either soft body or cloth physics, so I can bounce objects off of them. And I also want it to be connected to two points that move around.

Theres a similar post [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2487/rig-a-rope-spanning-two-objects), but I can't get it to hook onto both objects. It will either hook onto one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work with a curve as suggested by [Greg Zaal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2487/rig-a-rope-spanning-two-objects#comment4195_2488), as you said the curve doesn't seem to want to stick to multiple hooks at once..

However it works fine for me using a mesh as explained in my [previous answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2488/599), and it still runs realtime at 24 fps for me:

[image]

[**Example .blend**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32320)

Comment: I never thought of using Soft Bodies like that, good idea. I always use a curve with hooks. (It sticks to multiple hooks for me)

Comment: Ok it works great! is there a way to animate the string shorter and longer? like without it being so loose?

Comment: @DragonHeart You can increase the tension by adjusting the *Pull* value in *soft body edges*. To actually make it longer or shorter, adjust the initial mesh. You might be able to animate the length with shapekeys, but I haven't tested that yet..

Comment: Just tested it. It worked! Thanks for the big help!

Comment: @David Now I'm curious.. Can you upload a .blend?