# How to create a cable/wire for animation?

Tags: animation, physics, soft-body

So I've created a "noodle" with a path and a bezier Circle that has soft body so that when I click play it will drop and flop about.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is have one of the cubes stationary while the other moves around having the noodle between them stretch and move around like its a cable.

Any tips on this?

Comment: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50574 ...move the "side-points". Btw this solution has "dynamic" lenght though.

Comment: [Rig a rope spanning two objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2487/2217), [Create a stretchy line between two objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18151/2217) and [How to simulate a rope?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/97749/2217) may be of some help to you.

Comment: And [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13472/935) is a variation that changes the diameter of the cable as it is being stretched.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

Create a singe wire mesh composed of one edge, connecting the two cubes as desired.

Subdivide it a few times in *Edit Mode*. Create a new *Vertex Group* for the tips where you will only include the two end vertex (will be used for pinning later).

Now *Object Mode* select one of the cubes, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the cable so that both are selected. With both still selected enter *Edit Mode* on the cable and select only the corresponding tip vertex.

Hook that vertex to the cube by searching the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> menu for `Hook to Selected Object`. Repeat the process for the other cube with its corresponding end vertex.

Now activate a *Cloth* physics type for the cable, and pick the previously created *Vertex Group* for pinning.

Add a *Skin* modifier to give the cable some thickness

Add a *Subsurf* modifier to the cable mesh at the end of the stack to get a circular section cable and smoother results.

[image]

Rearrange your modifier stack if necessary to make sure both hooks are at the top of the list, followed immediately by the physics modifier.

You can now move the cubes and have the cable behave realistically.

[image]

You can optionally add a second *Subsurf* modifier to the rope before skinning to get smoother bending, or alternatively right before the physics modifier for a more detailed simulation. Beware that the second option will considerably affect simulation complexity, and may severely affect performance and calculation time.

Comment: Thanks for this one @Duarte Farrajota Ramos !

Comment: Thank you so very much! Works like a charm