# Dynamic rope or cable between 2 objects with AN

Tags: animation-nodes

So I have seen this tutorial here   https://youtu.be/BziV080OFHQ  and this is basically what I need, a rope between 2 empties that I can move around the scene and it will update dynamically. This method however changes the length of the rope between the empties. Is there a way to have a fixed length? So if I move the empties closer the rope will sag further, and moving the empties farther away will pull the rope tighter.

Anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks
steven

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121357/how-to-create-a-cable-wire-for-animation/121370#121370

Comment: That is using actual physics, not possible for this scene. the bake time would be months. Need a way to fake it with animation nodes.