# How can use a vertex group with a curve in the soft body modifier

Tags: bezier-curves, vertex-groups

I try to pin some points in curve.
I see we can add a soft body modifier in the curve and play with vertex group but i can't apply a vertex group to it.

How can use a vertex group with a curve in the soft body modifier.
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121357/how-to-create-a-cable-wire-for-animation/121370#121370

Comment: Yes thanks you but i don't want to use a skin modifier for design my mesh. I want to keep a procedural way. with a curve is better to redesign easy your design.