# How do I animate a rope in Blender 9.3?

Tags: animation, rigging, bezier-curves

I'm working on an animated short that features a claw machine, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to animate the chord that the claw dangles from. Here's where I'm at:

1. I modeled the claw itself, the thing it hangs from, and the chord that connects the two. I also have a belzier curve placed within the chord.
2. I want the chord to stay attached to the thing it hangs from and the claw. When the claw drops, the chord should stretch. When the claw rises, the chord should compress. If anyone needs a reference, here are some examples:

   [via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/cat-machine-toy-mEpQlZj0WpLSo)

   [via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/Millions-claw-machine-mahine-grab-controller-gSYt69qpvE8Ig56Kdm)
3. I also want to achieve that swing effect that you see when the claw moves.

I've tried watching tutorials on how to accomplish this, but every one I could had version 2.8, and I'm using version 2.93, so most of the tips they give in the tutorials I've seen don't apply. If anyone has any tips on how to do all of this in Blender 2.93, that'd be great.

Comment: so do you need to use physics or are you ok to fake physics?

Comment: Well that depends. A lot of the tutorials seemed to imply that armatures are the most efficient way to animate the chord, instead of something like hooking some of the vertices to empty objects. So as long as armatures don't interfere with fake physics I guess I wouldn't mind.

Comment: "as long as armatures don't interfere with fake physics", what do you mean, do you plan to use physics? If not you could use Spline IK for example, it would allow to animate your curve, see my third solution here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116124/how-to-rig-a-cartoon-style-hose-limb-cartoon-arm/116128

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121357/how-to-create-a-cable-wire-for-animation