# Create an animated dotted line

Tags: animation

I want to make this kind of animated dotted line:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mFa2iI_Nn0.

I will keep the camera fixed. The only thing I want to generate is the animated dotted line between 2 points. Like the youtube tutorial I have

- deleted the cube
- added a big plane
- added a nurbspath
- added a little plane

After I have added 2 modifiers to this plane, an array (with fixed count on x axis and relative offset) and a curve (with the nurbspath like object).
The last step is generating the animation by keyframing the 1frame with 
relative offset in minimum, and keyframing frame 250 with 
relative offset in maximum. All is exactly like in the youtube tutorial. I have added two LocRot keyframed an yet absolutely no movement between the two keyframes has been generated.

I have added a screen of the blender file to help you.

[image]

And so, how can I generate with Blender this animated dotted line ?

Comment: The video you linked shows you how to create the dotted line in Blender.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Dotted line on curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21060/dotted-line-on-curve)