# Attaching a nurbspath to a mesh (to create a rope attached to an object)

Tags: physics, soft-body

I'm trying to create a simulation of a phone receiver which is attached to the phone base via a phone cord.  I want the cord to dangle and stretch the same as a real coiled phone would, but without the headache of manually animating it.

After reading several tutorials and watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lg7jxAMs60Q) helpful video, I've created what I think is a realistic looking phone cord using a nurbspath and a curve circle to provide the bevel shape.

However I now don't know how to attach the cord at both ends to my phone receiver and phone base meshes.  I then jumped straight back into the tutorials and quickly determined that hooks might be what I was after.  However I've been flicking through youtube tutorials for a bit now and I'm not sure I understand the full behaviour of a hook.

I have tried to do the following:
1. Select my phone receiver (the handset).
[image]

2. Select the phone cord (nurbspath).
   [image]
3. Tab into edit mode.
4. Select only the first vertices on the path.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and select "Hook to Selected Object".
   [image]

The result is that I can move my phone receiver and it pulls along the first vertices of the nurbspath.
[image]

But when I hit the Play button the nurbs path just falls away from the handset as if no hook exists.
[image]

I will take a good bet I'm doing it all wrong.  Happy to take suggestions of a better way to do this.

Comment: If you make a hook and parent them to the objects, that should do it. What didn't work? Images or a .blend would help a lot. Also see if this question helps: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2487/rig-a-rope-spanning-two-objects?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm working on getting images together now.  The question you suggested was one I had already read.  In there they suggest using cloth simulation, but I wasn't sure if that would work for my coiled cord.

Comment: Ok I've tried to implement the solution you suggested using a cloth sim and it's clear now this is the better way to go about this.  I thought I needed to simulate the cord using a curve, instead it seems best to make a mesh (from the curve if required) and then simulate it from there.  Thanks again.