# Animation of Rope Cloth Simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

I wanted to animate this rope using the cloth simulation. The end result I was looking for, was to just have a rope fall and curl on the floor. What I got instead after baking for an eternity, was a string that just smashes and folds like thin paper into the floor and explodes into a bunch of tiny balls. What the heck?

This first image, rope looks fine.
[image]

Here, as I zoom in after playing a few frames, the rope breaks into sections and starts deforming for some reason.
[image]

And here, all the balls start to fly out and just makes absolutely no sense.
[image]

The method I used to create this rope using an extruded circle, then aligning an extruded circle with a curve using the curve modifier, and had applied an array modifier (hence the broken up sections). I ended up removing the curve as I just wanted the mesh.
Any ideas why my method of creating a rope isn't working properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate a rope?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/how-to-simulate-a-rope)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos There are several methods in creating this, I would like to know why this one isn't working as logically (to me at least) this shouldn't be happening in the simulation.

Comment: Hard to tell without following your workflow or seeing your settings. Maybe you didn't remove doubles, or one of your modifiers split your geometry creating a mesh with separate chunks, which on impact blew apart. Low simulation precision or incorrect collision settings may also cause bunching up results

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/97383/29586