# How can I build a dynamic animated stiff cable?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I´m trying for hours to animate a stiff cable for our client. So you can imagine time is running low ;). I've watched several tutorials on how to build dynamic cables, but I need a stiff one. A really good isolated stiff cable.

The objects:

1. Cable Mount -> Pin point Nr1 (always fixed)
2. Turning Point of cable -> at this object the cable will be wrapped
   around (180°) and comes parallel back to the mount.
3. Moving object -> Pin point Nr2 (will be animated and moved, object
   rotation should affect the cable.

What I´ve tried so far:
- Inverse kinetic armature: stuck at the turning point, should be a tighter curve than the bending of the rest of the cable
– Cloth Simulation: the stiffness is not the desired one, also the collision and self collision don't work as expected. Gravity and weight are off, that's fine, but if I move the Object (Pin point Nr2) back, the cable should be pushed back also. Currently it makes a small turn...

So, if anybody has a suggestion or tutorial, please let me know.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you give an image example of what you mean by a stiff cable?

Comment: Hi PGmath, for example an USB Cable, or HDMI Cable.

Comment: Perhaps you failed to get the correct stiffness because you didn't change the default 1 kg weight in soft-body to something more realistic (for USB cable ~ `5 g` or `0.005 kg`). You may also want to increase Edges->Bending a little. Wrapping the cable: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/93623/60486

Comment: Thank you Broady, I will try this. I reduced the weight to zero and used the cloth modifier. Perhaps I should try the Soft Body Modifier